# Как кликнуть по ссылке?

Tags: javascript

Нужно по очередно клинуть по ссилке, пробую так

```
window.content.document.getElementsByClassName('u А')[0].click();
```

Но что то не кликает оно.
Вот весь код HTML.

```
<td class="u"><a href="/test">1</a></td><td class="o"></td>
<td class="u"><a href="/test">1</a></td><td class="o"></td>
<td class="u"><a href="/test">1</a></td><td class="o"></td>
<td class="u"><a href="/test">1</a></td><td class="o"></td>
<td class="u"><a href="/test">1</a></td><td class="o"></td>
```

Подскажите как по ссилке клик сделать, а выбор ссылке я уже сам может сделаю.

Comment: А элемент получаете нормально, перед тем как клик вызвать? Есть ли в переменной `content` свойство `document`?

Comment: @vp_arth бог его знает, я в js не селен. Пробовал еще такой вариант window.content.document.getElementsByClassName('u').window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();

Говорит.  is undefined, line 1

Comment: _getElementsByClassName_ принимает в качестве параметра _класс_, в предоставленном Html нет ни одного элемента с классом `u A`

Comment: [window.content: _**This feature is non-standard** and is not on a standards track. **Do not use it** on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/content)

Comment: Ну, тут не только бог знает, уверяю вас) `document.querySelectorAll('.u a')[0].click()` попробуйте

Comment: @Grundy угу, вот выбрал window.content.document.getElementsByClassName('u')[0].click(); а по ссылке внутри дале как клик сделать?

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо, работает.

Comment: @vp_arth еще вопрос. А как посчитать все ссылке в <td class="u"> и в переменную затолкать их число не подскажете? Это было бы вообше круто.

Comment: [Вот тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) должно быть об этом написано

Comment: @vp_arth че то ноль возвращает. 

elementList = window.content.document.querySelectorAll('.br .u a');
alert(elementList.length);

Answer (score 0):

Во первых надо `document.getElementsByClassName("u")`. Во вторых - при нажатии на ссылку вылезает попап(всплывающие окно), а он может вызван только действиями пользавателя.
Если же вам надо кликнуть на ссылку без открытия попапа, то тогда у вас всё работает кроме селектора в начале.

Comment: _Во первых надо document.getElementsByClassName("u").firstChild_ - ты пробовал использовать код. который советуешь? `getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию, у этой коллекции **нет** поля/свойства _firstChild_, поэтому `document.getElementsByClassName("u").firstChild` - **всегда** будет возвращать _undefined_